# Which AppClip is going to be invoked if several ones are added to Apple App Site Association (AASA) file?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, apple-appclips

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website) says:

> The following code shows the content to add. Note how the value for the apps key is an array that contains the app identifier of the App Clip. In many cases, the array contains only one entry. However, it can contain entries for multiple App Clips.
>
> ```
> {
>    "appclips": {
>        "apps": ["ABCDE12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"]
>    }
> ...
> }
> ```

If I add several AppClips (obviously with the same associated domain) how will system decide which one to invoke?